# Observable angular not observed

Tags: angular, observable

This is my first time making my own observable, and i'm not sure if i'm doing it right because the data doesn't show when loaded, i see it in the console but the component doesn't refresh...

I retrieve the ids of my accounts and I make a request to retrieve the accounts then I would like to create an observable of Account [] from the table I just created

account service:

```js
     getListFriendsNoConfirmation(): Observable<Account []> {
        return this.itSMe().pipe(
          switchMap((me: Account) => {
            return this.post('account/friendNoConfirmation', HelperAccount.toUpdatePayload(me))
          }),
            switchMap((resp: ApiResponse)=>{
              if(resp != null){
                let nofriends: Account [] = [];
                let ids= resp.data as number [];
                ids.forEach((id:number)=>{
                  this.getOneAccount(id).subscribe((account: Account)=>{
                    nofriends.push(account);
                  })
                })
                return of(nofriends);
              }else{
                return []
              }
    
    
            })
        )
      }
    
      getOneAccount(id: number): Observable<Account>{
        return this.getWithName('account/one/',id.toString()).pipe(
          map((resp: ApiResponse)=>{
            return HelperAccount.fromDtoToAccount(resp.data as AccountDto);
          })
        )
      }
```

component.ts:

```js
    ngOnInit(): void {
       
        this.accountService.getListFriendsNoConfirmation().subscribe((accounts: Account [])=>{
          this.nofriends$ = accounts;
          console.log(accounts);
        })
      }
```

Comment: How do you declare and use the `nofriends$` variable? I see that you put a `$` to that variable, a naming convetion for `Observables`, but you are expecting an `Account[]`. Could you share the template?

Comment: @ArthurPérez, I believe `return of(nofriends)` is happening before any of the `getOneAccount` (async) requests are completed. You can try to use a forkJoin maybe, instead of the forEach with push strategy
`const requests = ids.map(id => this.getOneAccount(id));
return forkJoin(requests);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `switchMap` is messy as you are returning empty array and then pushing items to it somewhere in the future. This not only makes your code less predictable, but also prevents angular from detecting changes of that array  (and this is what you probably see). Also you are returning array `[]` in `else` block instead of `observable` which will simply break `switchMap`.

Use `forkJoin` to build your array

```
 getListFriendsNoConfirmation(): Observable<Account []> {
    return this.itSMe().pipe(
      switchMap((me: Account) => {
        return this.post('account/friendNoConfirmation', HelperAccount.toUpdatePayload(me))
      }),
        switchMap((resp: ApiResponse)=>{
          if(resp != null){
            let ids= resp.data as number [];
            // if does not work, spread it first with forkJoin(...ids.map())
            return forkJoin(ids.map((id:number)=>this.getOneAccount(id)))            
          }else{
            return of([])
          }
        })
    )
  }
```

//useage

```
getListFriendsNoConfirmation().subscribe((acc:Account[])=>console.log(acc));
```

This way your pipeline will return alredy initialized array of accounts as `forkJoin` block the pipeline until all observables passed to it completes.

Also remember that you always need to subscribe, otherwise pipeline will not  be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few problems, first, you are not returning an observable if `resp` is null. It should be `else{ return of([]); }`

second, you should never do a subscribe when chining the observables, this doesn't work. use forkjoin instead:

```js
switchMap((resp: ApiResponse)=>{
  if(resp?.data === null || resp?.data === undefined || resp.data.length === 0){
    return of([]);
  }

  const nofriends$: Observable<Account>[] = (resp.data as number[]).map(
    id => this.getOneAccount(id)
  );
  return forkJoin(nofriends$);
)}
```

and maybe your last problem is in component.ts when you do `this.nofriends$ = accounts;`. At this point accounts is an array of account, and not an observable.
so it should be:

```js
public nofriends: Account[] = null;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.accountService.getListFriendsNoConfirmation().subscribe((accounts: Account [])=>{
    this.nofriends = accounts;
    console.log(accounts);
  })
}
```

or if you want

```js
public nofriends$: Observable<Account[]> = this.accountService.getListFriendsNoConfirmation().pipe(
  tap(accounts => {console.log(accounts)})
);
```

and then you subscribe to nofriends$ in the HTML using an async pipe